# How to apply gradient onto a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm really glad to find this great place.
I am a developer, so please don't mind my novice question, thank you.

My question is

How to apply gradient onto a shape and put 3 images into one(PhotoShop CS6).

Here are these pictures:

Wizard
[image]

Background
[image]

Effect
[image]

Let me explain it in more details.

I want to use the Background and put the wizard onto the background with the effect like the Effect picture.

Now what I have done is I have got the wizard shape,

What I am going to do:

1. clean the rest of other parts on the wizard to make it "clean"(I will use Eraser, any other more effective tool?)
2. Put the wizard onto the background
3. Apply the gradient onto the wizard and put some text around the wizard with same gradient. (Don't know how to do it here)

What I concern is:

1. What color to apply on the gradient wizard so that the background color and "front" color are not conflict.(Don't know what color to choose)
2. I still feel that I miss something to make the whole picture look like a splash screen on my app.  May be a badge and write the app name on the badge?(Need your idea)

Thank you!

---

Update

Now I have got the wizard shape and make all color consistent on her whole body.
[image]

Comment: not steal mate, take a look my update. @Scott

Comment: Fair enough.. first image clearly was just getting around watermarks.

Comment: hi @Scott I have got rid of the watermarks. do you have any idea how to apply gradient onto this wizard? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click the layer on the layers windows shown then a the panel below shown should popup.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot mate~! it works~!! huh, after I put the wizard onto the background, I feel that there are too many things(or too messy) in the background, but I don't know what could be a better background. Do you have any suggestions?